# "Adding constant symbols" in Model Theory.

Tags: model-theory

What is going on when we "add constant symbols" to extend a language L.

A new constant is not in the "alphabet" of L. C is, for example, just { 0, 1 } in many cases, but C could be an infinite set. Constants are distinguished elements of the universe. But the universe is associated with the models, $\mathcal{M}$.

So, frequently we add new elements to C, or rather think of the signature as $\sigma = (C \cup C_0, F, R, \sigma')$ where $C_0$ is a set of new constants.

Often we add a whole bunch of constants corresponding to a set A in some particular L-structure $\mathcal{M}$. So $A \subseteq M$ (M is the universe of $\mathcal{M}$) So, the elements in A correspond to elements in the universe.

$L(\underline{M})$ is L with extra constants for every element in the universe of $\mathcal{M}$. So, a bigger language.

Why are we doing this? We are "considering formulas as sentences in an extended language." How will the constants help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason is to show that there are models of $L$ with some property.  If we add constant symbols to $L$, we can also add axioms involving those symbols.  Any model of the expanded structure is still a model of $L$, so if we can show that the new symbols and axioms do not cause a contradiction we have shown that there exist models of $L$ with the desired property.

A classic example is to show Peano Arithmetic has models with nonstandard elements.  We know (or assume) the usual PA axioms are consistent.  We now add a distinguished element $c$ along with a countably infinite set of axioms $c \gt 0, c \gt S(0), c \gt SS(0), \dots$  For any finite set of the axioms, the usual $\Bbb N$ is still a model, because there are only finitely many of the $c \gt $ and we can just take $c$ to be a large enough standard number.  The compactness theorem now tells us that the whole set has to have a model, but we cannot have $c$ being any of the standard numbers, so it must be nonstandard.