# Extending a language by adding a constant symbol

Tags: logic

Here is the definition from Lou van den Dries's lecture notes, pg.32:

"Let $\mathcal A$ be an $L$-structure with underlying set $A$, and let $C\subseteq A$. We extend $L$ to a language $L_C$ by adding a constant symbol $\underline c$ for each $c\in C$, called the $name$ of $c$."

I do not understand why we add symbols this way to a language. My lecturer told me that it was because of being able to definine $satisfiability$, but I do not understand what $satisfiability$ is either. I know this is a duplicate of ["Adding constant symbols" in Model Theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072035/adding-constant-symbols-in-model-theory) However, I did not understand the answer to the duplicate unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, we know how to evaluate the truth value of *sentences*, i.e. formulae without free variables.

We are able to judge if $\underline 0=\underline 0$ is true, but what about $x+ \underline 0= \underline 0$ ? It depends on the variable $x$...

What about the quantified expression :

> $\exists x (x+ \underline 0= \underline 0)$ ?

It is a *sentence* (no free variable) and in order to decide if it is true or not in e.g. the strucyure $\mathbb N$, we have to check if some object of the domain (some natural number) satisfy it.

This case is simple : it is enough to consider the number $0$. Thus, using its *name* : $\underline 0$, we have that $\underline 0= \underline 0$ is true in $\mathbb N$, and thus, applying the relevant semantical clause for the satisfaction relation :

> $\mathbb N \vDash \exists x (x = \underline 0)$  if and only if $\mathbb N \vDash (\underline a = \underline 0)$ for some $a \in \mathbb N$,

we have that it holds with $0$ as $a$.

But what about the quantified expression :

> $\forall x (x+ \underline 0= \underline 0)$ ?

Now we are in trouble, because the language has only one "name" : $\underline 0$. Thus, the "trick" : add a new *constant* symbol $\underline a$ for every $a \in \mathbb N$ and then apply the clause :

> $\mathbb N \vDash \forall x (x = \underline 0)$  if and only if $\mathbb N \vDash (\underline a = \underline 0)$ for all $a \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

One possible use for extending your language is for doing formal semantics, and defining satisfiability is part of that.

For example, suppose we want to formally define what it takes for a statement like $\forall x P(x)$ to be true, given some interpretation $I$ that has defined some domain of objects $A$ as well as has provided a meaning for the predicate symbol $P$. So we want a mathematical formula that states that all objects from A have the property as defined by P, and one way of doing that is to try to say that all objects * satisfy* the formula P(x), i.e. that P(x) is true for all objects in $A$.

Ok, that seems easy enough, right? Just say $\forall a \in A: I(P(a)) = True$ (or, what is often used: $\forall a \in A: I \vDash P(a)$).

The problem with this, however, is that we are taking an object from our domain and plug it into a logical expression as if it were a constant symbol. But, our language may not have a constant symbol for all of those objects defined! For example, in Peano Arithmetic we typically only have a contant symbol for 0; if we ever want to talk about 1, we have to write something like $s(0)$. And sometimes we may not have *any* constant symbols. And finally, even if we have constant symbols, then that constant symbol is still different from the object it represents, e.g. I could choose to use $c$ to represent the number $0$, which means that if I want to say that $0$ satisfies the formula $Even(x)$, I have to say that $Even(c)$ is True, rather than that $Even(0)$ is True; again, objects from the domain are not the same as constant symbols from our language!

So, to say that all objects from $A$ satisfy some formula, we have to (temporarily) introduce a new constant symbol for our objects. That is what is happening here.

Comment: @Bram28- So, logical expressions only accept constant symbols, right?

Comment: Correct. Logical expressions are sentences of a logical language, where that language consists of logical symbols (like $\neg$, $\land$, $\forall$, or $=$), and non-logical symbols (constant symbols like $c$, predicate symbols like P, and function symbols like f), but these are all different from the objects that those symbols and expressions and sentences are about.

Comment: I should add that a predicate can also take variables of course! Anyway, if you fo formal semantics or model theory, it is *crucial* to distinguish between the domain you are talking about, and the logical expressions you use to talk about that domain and the objects in it.

Comment: @Serpenche In Mauro's answer, it is the difference between $0$ and $\underline{0}$: the first is the mathematical object $0$, while the second is the constant symbol we use in logic to refer to that object.